# SQuirreL SQL for Oracle & IBM UDB

Tags: squirrel-sql

I tried using SQuirreL SQL for Oracle & UDB databases, I see some functionality are missing for both Oracle & UDB. Have anyone faced/observed similar issues and any workaround/fixes for the same.

Below are the issues which I see:

Oracle using ojdbc7 driver:
It is not differentiating IOT or Partitioned tables visually.
Script for IOT table is incorrect.
Column level stats of the table are missing.
Constraints  are missing in Object navigator.
Partitions and  subpartition details are missing in Objects Navigator.
Referential constraints or triggers are missing under tables.
Do not see an option to generate  AWR/ASH/SQL reports.

UDB using db2jcc4 driver:
Does not show trigger
Does not show Sequence
Does not show Constraint
Does not show Procedure text
Not able to create procedures
No option to cancel the running query
No option for query explain plan

Any input will be helpful, thanks in advance.